# During the ajax call url get distrubs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have following url

```
 var url ="cruuntest/ContactGrabber/GetData?code=4/8KxuRU8WYRUzruYPEeXo9wOM0bOi.Yvd5Wc6y5rIWEnp6UAPFm0H6Lj2rjQI"
```

And I am doing

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            success: function (obj) {
                $ContactImporter.createContactGridModel(obj);

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('error = ' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

But it redirects to

```
http://localhost:80/cruuntest/ContactGrabber/Index/cruuntest/ContactGrabber/GetData?code=4/8KxuRU8WYRUzruYPEeXo9wOM0bOi.Yvd5Wc6y5rIWEnp6UAPFm0H6Lj2rjQI
```

I do not know why? I have hosted my application on IIS 8.  When I am running this with my code wihout hosting it in IIS it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running the ajax call from this page:

/cruuntest/ContactGrabber/Index

And so it just appends your query to the URL:

/cruuntest/ContactGrabber/Index (appended here, which is what you are seeing)

**You need to start with the '/' to the start of your URL, like this:**

/cruuntest/ContactGrabber/GetData?code=4/8KxuR

That / tells it to start at the root not where the current page is.

That will solve your problem I think.